How to decipher cryptic Intel intrinsic names and acronyms
When you start dealing with SIMD instructions, you notice intrinsics have names like
_mm_dp_pd
_mm_mul_pd

After a little bit (or years) of squinting at the documentation, you start to notice some shorthands:

d means "double-precision float"
p is short for "packed" (whatever that means... maybe "plural")
dp means "dot product"

and then you think you're good, but then you encounter gibberish like
_mm_maddubs_epi16
_mm_mpsadbw_epu8
_mm256_dpwuuds_epi32

and you start to go mad(dubs?) trying to figure out what the heck dpwuuds means and how the heck your brain is supposed to decipher it in a sane amount of time.
Is there any sort of table or guide to help mere mortals decipher what these acronyms mean?

The intel intrinsics guide?

You'll get used to it.

maddubs is multiply-add unsigned byte with saturation. dpwuuds is dot product word unsigned by unsigned to dword with saturation. You can see the notation isn't even consistent, I'd say it should be dpuwuwds.

@fuz: That's objectively false! Been using these for > 10 years and still aren't used to them and still have no clue what some of them stand for.

@Jester: Yeah, the inconsistency has been throwing me off too. It'd be awesome if you can post an answer with the most common abbreviations and a few examples.

Those intrinsic names reflect the asm mnemonics.  Sometimes the intrinsic names are worse and less obvious than the mnemonics, with seemingly arbitrary choice of _epi16 vs. _epi8 for instructions that widen or narrow (like vpmaddubsw = _mm_maddubs_epi16 vs. pmaddwd = _mm_madd_epi16.  Totally ridiculous, the first widens from 8 to 16 (Packed Multply-ADD Unsigned Byte Signed Word), the second from 16 to 32.  But one was SSE2, one was SSSE3, so they weren't named at the same time.  /sigh.)

psadbw is packed Sum of Absolute Differences, a common operation in video encoding (searching for similar pixels).  mpsadbw is a multi-SAD at some offset.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mpsadbw

Is there a guide?  Yes, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html  - just put anything in the search box.  But that guide fails to decode the  naming!  So find the corresponding asm mnemonic from the intrinsics guide and look it up in the asm manual (Intel PDF, or scraped into HTML on https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/)

madd = multiply-add, the integer equivalent of FP FMA.
Some other ISAs call it a multiply-accumulate (MAC).

Is there a guide?

Yes, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html  - just put anything in the search box.  But that guide fails to decode the  naming!  So find the corresponding asm mnemonic from the intrinsics guide and look it up in the asm manual (Intel PDF, or scraped into HTML on https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) where the entry titles include a short summary which the mnemonic is based on, like PMADDUBSW — Multiply and Add Packed Signed and Unsigned Bytes
The intrinsic names you mention reflect the asm mnemonics.  That's kind of a fallback if they can't come up with their own name that you have to remember separately from the asm mnemonic.  (I always think in terms of the asm I want, and write C that will hopefully compile to it.)
Sometimes the intrinsic names are worse and less obvious than the mnemonics.
The choice of _epi16 vs. _epi8 often seem arbitrary for instructions that widen or narrow.  I generally have to look up the intrinsic name for the instruction I know I want in those cases.  Like vpmaddubsw = _mm_maddubs_epi16 vs. pmaddwd = _mm_madd_epi16.  Totally ridiculous, the first widens from 8 to 16 (Packed Multiply-ADD Unsigned Byte Signed Word), the second from 16 to 32.  But one was SSE2, one was SSSE3, so they weren't named at the same time.  /sigh.
It's also pretty arbitrary whether they use "shuffle" or "permute", and we have messes like vpermilpd having _mm_permute_pd (or permutevar with a control vector), where the asm naming emphasized that it was an AVX in-lane shuffle.  But then AVX2 came along and added lane-crossing shuffles with granularity smaller than 128-bit like vpermpd, so the intrinsic naming had to do something to disambiguate, choosing _mm256_permutex_epi64 with the x indicating lane-crossing.
So it's kinda backwards and you just have to remember that the people naming the intrinsics often did a bad job and made short-sighted choices (common for Intel, including in their ISA design.)

psadbw is packed Sum of Absolute Differences, a common operation in video encoding (searching for similar pixels).  mpsadbw (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mpsadbw) is a multi-SAD (taking a byte offset as an immediate), intended to avoid the need for separate shuffling.  But it's not fast enough to be worth using most of the time.  e.g. x264's exhaustive motion-search does better without it, I think partly by ruling out some combinations so it's not pure brute-force, and by shuffling efficiently with other instructions.  The P is of course for Packed, and coming at the start of the mnemonic it means integer.  Normally the C intrinsics omit the leading p (like paddb is _mm_add_epi8), but in this case the p isn't leading.  So we get _mm_mpsadbw_epu8 which is just the instruction mnemonic as the name part (with the usual _mm_ prefix and _size suffix).

p is short for "packed" (whatever that means... maybe "plural")

Packed is as opposed to Scalar.  Like _mm_add_ss (Add Scalar Single) only changes the low element, copying the top 3 elements from the source operand.  You don't normally use intrinsics for instructions like [v]addss, you just write scalar code which a compiler doesn't vectorize.  But they exist and can occasionally be useful if you have something interesting in the high elements and want to add/mul/sqrt or whatever on just the low element.
Related:

What are the names and meanings of the intrinsic vector element types, like epi64x or pi32?
Meaning of suffix "x" in intrinsics like "_mm256_set1_epi64x"


vaddss etc adds the lowest element, copies elements 1-3 and zeros elements 4-max (which may be consistent with how AVX was introduced, but almost useless, unless one only uses elements 0-3).

@chtz: yeah, the AVX form is only useful if you're using 128-bit vectors, or actual scalar.  If they'd made it copy the upper 128, you'd need vzeroupper in functions that used it, when they call or return to anything that might use legacy SSE.  And it's a rare enough operation that it presumably wasn't worth supporting the 128 vs. 256 bit in the VEX prefix for the existing opcode to allow both XMM or YMM versions of vaddss. (Extra hardware in the decoder, and a bit in the uop signalling something the execution unit has to support.)

@chtz:  Interesting idea, though, it wouldn't need a new opcode to support vaddss ymm, src1, src2.  The encoding for https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/addss is VEX.LIG which means the Length bit (128 vs. 256) is ignored.  (And so is the W bit, it's also WIG.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix  So there's an unused bit in the encoding which has that purpose for most SIMD instructions like vaddps.
